# Edit state variables in React devtools when using a Zustand store

Tags: reactjs, react-devtools, zustand

In React devtools you can easily edit and toggle state variables - either stored locally, in Context, or with some fancy add-ons like redux devtools.

Is there a way to do that with Zustand store hooks? It seems to me like they're just readonly.

[image: Zustand hooks/vars]

Comment: You find a solution to this?

Comment: @jamesemanon my experience got slightly better with the use of redux devtools and zustand: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nImE4P8Wc_M